# What does unknown app version mean in playstore

Tags: android, google-play

I got unknown version in play-store. What does this mean? I am confused. Every time I upload app increase version code. Can any one tell me what happened?

And

App icon get gray box  too in play-store app list. What does this mean?
I halt two roll-out cause of some issues. Is that gray box is caused by halted releases?

[image]